# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to read images from the file but it's giving me this error-

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function
>   'cv::cvtColor'

I've also tried changing the "/" on src_path to "\" but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Here is the code-

```
def create_imageset(excludeHardClasses=True):
    #Variables
    images_path = "C:/Users/bipin/Anaconda3/ASLConvNet-master/src/images/"

    #Read for images folder 
    image_files = [f for f in listdir(images_path) if isfile(join(images_path, f))]

    #processing and reading image files
    image_set = [] #contains all images

    for i in image_files : 
        #split 
        info = i.split('_')
        if excludeHardClasses and info[1] in exclude_label_list:
            continue
        if info[1] == 'o':
            info[1] = '0'
        if info[1] == 'v':
            info[1] = '2'

        matrix = cv2.imread(images_path + '/' + i)
        RGB_img = cv2.cvtColor(matrix, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: Are you sure your images have loaded correctly? It seems they haven't.

Comment: Could you please report what is the exact while you run your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember `isfile(join(images_path, f))` returns a [list of all regular files](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile), not only images.

I am suspecting you have read a file which is not an image. That makes your `matrix` variable `None`. When you call `cv2.cvtColor` with a `None` value you see this error.

If you are trying to read `png` files you can try

```
image_files = [f for f in listdir(images_path) if f.endswith(".png")]
```

Also, you may want to change

```
matrix = cv2.imread(images_path + '/' + i)
```

to

```
matrix = cv2.imread(join(images_path, i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `\\` instead of using `\`. Because in Python `\` is used to escape and to get `\` you have to use `\\`. That indicates the backslash option.

According to your code it should be

```
images_path = "C:\\Users\\bipin\\Anaconda3\\ASLConvNet-master\\src\\images\\"
```